# Function of uniform distribution

Tags: probability, uniform-distribution

If $X \sim U(0,1)$ and

$\begin{align} \\[10pt]
Y = {} &
\begin{cases} \frac 3 2 - X & \text{if } \frac 1 2 < X< 1 \\[10pt]
\frac 3 4 - X & \text{if } \frac 1 4 < X < \frac 1 2 \\[10pt]
\frac 3 8 - X & \text{if } \frac 1 8 < X < \frac 1 4 \\[10pt]
\text{and so on.}
\end{cases}
\end{align}$

How can we say that $Y$ has the same distribution of $X$?
Should I calculate $Y$ for every interval in which $X$ is contained, for example:

$Y= \frac 3 2 - X$ if $\frac 1 2 <X< 1$ means that in the interval $(\frac 1 2,1)$, $Y \sim U(\frac 1 2,1)$ or for

$Y=\frac 3 4 - X$ if $\frac 1 4 <X< \frac 1 2$ means that in the interval $(\frac 1 4,\frac 1 2)$ $Y \sim U(\frac 1 2,\frac 5 2)$?

But if this is correct I don't see how $X \sim Y$.

I've also tried to draw a graph of the two random variables in the square$[0,1]x[0,1]$ but the situation is still unclear.

Comment: Hello, and welcome to Math SE. Thank you very much for using MathJax. Do you think you could explain your own thoughts or what you have attempted thus far? That way, we can help you—and others—the best we can.

Comment: @ChaseRyanTaylor I uploaded the whole question as you suggested

Answer (score 0):

If X lies between 1/2 and 1 then Y= 3/2- X lies between 3/2- 1= 1/2 and 3/2- 1= 1/2 the same as X.

If X lies between 1/4 and 1/2 then Y= 3/4- X lies between 3/4- 1/2= 1/4 and 3/4- 1/4= 1/2, the same as X.

If X lies between 1/8 and 1/4, then Y= 3/8- X lies between 3/8- 1/4]= 1/8 and 3/8- 1/8= 1/4, the same as X.

Yes, Y has exactly the same distribution as X.

Comment: Thank you for the answer. Why If X lies between 1/2 and 1 Y is not  3/2- 1= 1/2 and 3/2- 1/2= 1?

Comment: Can we say in this case that $P(X=Y)=0$? If $X$ has the same distribution of $X$ how can this be possible?

Comment: Given X as a **continuous** probability density, the probability that X is **any** specific value is 0.  That does not mean that X never has that value.  The idea that "P(X)= 0 means that X cannot happen" is only true for discrete probability distriubutions.

Comment: So if the two random variables are equal just in one point we can say $P(X=Y)=0$. Did I understand correctly? But in this case doesn't $X$ and $Y$  assume  the same exactly values and are equal in all points?